# Input tensor is not an XLA tensor: CPUFloatType

Tags: amazon-web-services, cpu, tensor

RuntimeError: torch_xla/csrc/aten_xla_bridge.cpp:73 : Check failed: xtensor
*** Begin stack trace ***
tsl::CurrentStackTrace()
torch_xla::bridge::GetXlaTensor(at::Tensor const&)

```
    PyCFunction_Call
    _PyObject_MakeTpCall

    _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
    _PyFunction_Vectorcall
    _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
    _PyFunction_Vectorcall
    _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
    _PyFunction_Vectorcall
    _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    _PyFunction_Vectorcall
    _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
    PyEval_EvalCode



    PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags
    Py_RunMain
    Py_BytesMain
    __libc_start_main
    _start
```

*** End stack trace ***
Input tensor is not an XLA tensor: CPUFloatType

I tried compiling flair ner-eng-large model to AWS inf2 neuron.

```
    tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair_entity/best-model.pt")
    tensors = tagger.embeddings.prepare_tensors(sentences)
    example_inputs_paraphrase = tensors['input_ids'], tensors['token_lengths'], tensors['attention_mask'], tensors['overflow_to_sample_mapping'], tensors['word_ids']
    script_module = torch_neuronx.trace(wrapper, example_inputs_paraphrase)
```